# Spark: updating column with values from list based on condition

Tags: apache-spark

For below given input df, i am trying to output below output df in spark i.e. adding new column "new1" in output df and the value of new1 column is such that it should contain the non-value of fn column value for all rows prior to it if they are less than fn value and id value.

```
input df:
+---+---+
| id| fn|
+---+---+
|  1|  0|
|  1|  0|
|  2|  0|
|  2|  0|
|  3|  4|
|  5|  0|
|  5|  0|
|  6|  7|
+---+---+

output wanted is:
+---+---+----+
| id| fn|new1|
+---+---+----+
|  1|  0|   4|
|  1|  0|   4|
|  2|  0|   4|
|  2|  0|   4|
|  3|  4|   4|
|  5|  0|   7|
|  5|  0|   7|
|  6|  7|   7|
+---+---+----+
```

Comment: why not use `withColumn` with `when`... `df.withColumn("new1", when(col("fn")<fn_value_list(0),fn_value_list(0)).otherwise(col("fn"))`

Comment: what if you have more than one element in the list ? can we get example for that. the question is not clear yet

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for replies.
I used udf (i could have used above first reply too, but as i had some more logic to incorporate, hence i did it using udf for easy reading).

The code i did is as below, which is working fine for my question.

```
val df = Seq((1, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 0), (3, 4),(5, 0), (5, 0), (6, 7)).toDF("id", "fn")

        val df1 = df.filter(df("fn") > 0)
        val fn_value_list = df1.select("fn").rdd.map(r => r(0)).collect.toList 
        fn_value_list.foreach(println)

        def udfFunc(idval : Int, fnval : Int) : Int = { 
                for(fn_val_list <- fn_value_list) {
                        if(idval <= fn_val_list.asInstanceOf[Int] &&  fnval <= fn_val_list.asInstanceOf[Int])
                                return fn_val_list.asInstanceOf[Int]
                }   
                return fnval
        }   
        val myUdf = udf(udfFunc _)
        var df10 = df.withColumn("new1", myUdf(df("id"), df("fn")))
        df10.show
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the details there and delete this answer.